# Regex is not matching (for url)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

here we go

```
private static readonly string _regexPattern = @"[/]api[/]v[0-9].[0-9][/]Subscriber[/][0-9]{10}";

public override string GenerateRowKey(LogEvent logEvent, string suffix = null)
{
    var logResult = $"{logEvent.Properties["RequestPath"]}";

    var regex = new Regex(logResult);
    var fh = regex.IsMatch(_regexPattern);

    ---
}
```

logResult is `"/api/v1.0/Subscriber/2727272727"`

Have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: `"Have no idea why this doesn't work"` -- Well what is it _supposed_ to do, we cant read your mind.  We need a problem statement, sample input/output, etc

Comment: @DavidG for "/" in url. Like there is [api] for "api"

Comment: According to online regex tester like http://regexstorm.net/tester your regex works.

Comment: @maccettura regex is not match. If I had more info about what exactly isn't working I wouldn't ask for help

Comment: @hakamairi but it doesn't work in the code

Answer (score 2):

Your passing the pattern/text in the wrong order, the ctor wants a pattern for later testing with `IsMatch()`:

```
var regex = new Regex(_regexPattern);
var fh = regex.IsMatch(logResult);
```

There is also a [`static IsMatch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_System_String_) thats less to type & uses an internal cache.

Comment: regex.IsMatch(logResult)?

Comment: THank you so much. Fully me

Comment: @hakamairi Yup, I've fixed it

Comment: You may want to anchor your pattern with ^/$ to avoid substring matches too.